# Deconstructing arrays for the function arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, decomposition

I have

```
function f(a,b,c) {}
```

and

```
const arr = [1,2,3]
```

What do I need to call

```
f(arr)
```

__________________________________________?

Answer (score 0):

One this you can do is:

```
f.apply({}, arr);
```